# Can preprocessor directives be used to import different header files for Mac and iOS?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I am writing a class library for Mac OS X and iOS to be released as a Cocoa Framework for OS X and a Static Library for iOS. To simplify matters, I intend to use multiple targets in Xcode. However, the classes on Mac OS X link against Cocoa.h whereas on iOS they link against Foundation.h.

My questions basically are:

- Could the Mac OS X framework link against Foundation.framework instead? Classes used within the framework are NSString, NSMutableString, and NSMutableArray.
- Or could I use preprocessor directives within the header files to control framework inclusion, e.g.

  ```
  #ifdef MacOSX
      #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
  #else
      #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #endif
  ```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181321/which-conditional-compile-to-use-to-switch-between-mac-and-iphone-specific-code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use these to separate platform dependent code (see `TargetConditionals.h`):

```
#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE 
    // iOS
#elif defined TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // iOS Simulator
#elif defined TARGET_OS_MAC
    // Other kinds of Mac OS
#else
    // Unsupported platform
#endif
```

Here's a [useful chart](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2010/8/16/TargetConditionalsh.html).

Comment: I did a bit of testing and corrected the code accordingly.  Apparently `TARGET_OS_MAC` is defined for iOS as well.  Best is really to look into `TargetConditionals.h` and see which macros suit your needs.  There's quite a few of them.

Comment: I believe now you need to use `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE`, instead of `#ifdef`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There's a couple problems: First, `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` will always be defined. It's defined as 0 sometimes, but it's still defined. Same with `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`. But, also, `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` will never be 1 unless `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is also 1. If you need to check for the iOS simulator specifically, you should do that check first, like: `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` / `#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE` / `#elif TARGET_OS_MAC` / `#endif`.

Answer (score 8):

It works like a charm:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
  #include "TargetConditionals.h"

  #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR  
  // ios simulator

  #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  // ios device

  #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
  // mac os 

  #else
  // Unsupported platform
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: I think this is the only answer here that will actually work.

Answer (score 2):

> - Could the Mac OS X framework link against Foundation.framework instead? Classes used within the framework are NSString, NSMutableString, and NSMutableArray.

Try it and see. If the compile fails, no. If it succeeds, yes.

> - Or could I use preprocessor directives within the header files to control framework inclusion, e.g.

Yes, you can. In fact, I believe that is the *only* way to do that.

Comment: Thank you. Thinking about it, Foundation is a framework, therefore I suppose there shouldn't be an issue. I'll give it a go and see!

Comment: Come to think of it, Core Plot does exactly what you want to do. If you have issues, check it out and see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
//iOS 
#else
//Mac
#endif
```