# Use pragma ifdef to conditionally compile the same protocol header for both mac and ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which conditional compile to use to switch between Mac and iPhone specific code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181321/which-conditional-compile-to-use-to-switch-between-mac-and-iphone-specific-code)

I've defined a protocol which should work just fine on both Mac and iOS.  However, one of the methods of the protocol would better return a specific class of object (rather than just 'id'), but the class is not a foundation class and thus varies on the two platforms (for example, UIButton and NSButton).

How can I use a pragma mark like `#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE` to include the same protocol header in two libraries, one built for iOS and one for Mac?

Here is my actual protocol and my (broken) attempt at conditional compilation

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SharedAppDelegate <NSObject>

#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@protocol UIApplicationDelegate;
+ (NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate> *)sharedAppDelegate;
#else
@protocol NSApplicationDelegate;
+ (NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate> *)sharedAppDelegate;
#endif

@end
```

One thing I know off the bat is that the target does not include the simulator, but I cannot find a solid example of one target which covers Mac and another all iOS incarnations.

Comment: It is similar - and trust me I had been looking for that question unsuccessfully for an hour before asking mine - but since this question has a specific example which has now been correctly resolved, I'd say it's different enough.  Thank you for the link though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're gonna kick yourself. It's `#if` not `#ifdef`. `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is a `#define` that is set to `1` for iOS and `0` for mac. You want to use the simple `#if`.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    NSLog(@"is iPhone or simulator");
#else
    NSLog(@"is mac... probably");
#endif
```

Also, you can't have a forward declaration of a protocol inside a protocol definition. You'll have to do something like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@protocol UIApplicationDelegate;
#else
@protocol NSApplicationDelegate;
#endif


@protocol SharedAppDelegate <NSObject>
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
+ (NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate> *)sharedAppDelegate;
#else
+ (NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate> *)sharedAppDelegate;
#endif
```

Comment: This works, but I haven't tested device vs simulator.  Apparently the TARGET_OS_IPHONE distinguishes these, where what I want is to distinguish Mac vs iOS, regardless of device.

Comment: I'm not sure where you picked up the idea that `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` evaluates differently between a device and the simulator, I've never heard that. If you want a macro to test for the simulator use `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`. `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` evaluates true for an iOS target.