# Macro condition for iOS and OSX code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macros

I need to support iOS and OSX in my shared library, whats the best Macro / Practise for conditioning iOS and OSX code

the bellow code doesn't work for some reason :/

```
- (NSString *)hostName {
    #ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
        return [[NSHost currentHost] localizedName];
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to build two separate libraries (which is what you need to do with the code posted in your question), or are you looking for a runtime solution?

Comment: Compiler directives can't be used for runtime checks. And I don't think you can build a shared library that supports both iOS and OS X. I believe you need two separate libraries since the processors are quite different. You might be able to build a single framework with separate slides for each. But either way, you end up compiling each separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Use #if rather than #ifdef
2. Check TARGET_OS_IPHONE first since TARGET_OS_MAC is defined to 1 for both platforms

See:
[Which conditional compile to use to switch between Mac and iPhone specific code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181321/which-conditional-compile-to-use-to-switch-between-mac-and-iphone-specific-code)