# Is there something like os(iOS) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, platform

Swift provides a special preprocessor directive called `os` to check what operating system you are running:

```
struct A {
#if os(iOS)
    let a: AvailableOnIOS
#elseif os(tvOS)
    let a: AvailableOnTVOS
#endif
}
```

I am interested if there is something similar in Objective-C that can be used like

```
@interface A: NSObject
#if os(iOS)
@property (nonatomic, strong) AvailableOnIOS* a;
#elseif os(tvOS)
@property (nonatomic, strong) AvailableOnTVOS* a;
#endif
@end
```

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181321/which-conditional-compile-to-use-to-switch-between-mac-and-iphone-specific-code ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you. Should I use `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE` instead of `#if os(iOS)` in Objective-C?

Comment: To be clear: You want to build an app that works on iOS and TV OS devices, and want a compiler directive that generates the correct code for each target?

Comment: The other thing we need to do sometimes is check code at runtime to see what device we are running on. It sounds like you instead want to compile different code for each platform?

Comment: @DuncanC I want a compiler directive that generates the correct code for each target, something like `os(iOS)` in Swift.

Comment: Yeah, you should look at the link Martin provided. Yes, in Objective-C you want something like `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

```
@interface A : NSObject
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
    @property(nonatomic) AvailableOnIOS * a;
#elsif TARGET_OS_TV
    @property(nonatomic) AvailableOnTVOS * a;
#endif
@end
```

Do not use `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` as that includes all embedded systems. Just as `TARGET_OS_MAC` includes all Apple systems.

To quote from Apple's `TargetConditionals.h` header:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    TARGET_OS_MAC                                     |
| +-----+ +------------------------------------------------------------+ +-----------+ |
| |     | |                  TARGET_OS_IPHONE                          | |           | |
| |     | | +-----------------+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ +--------+ | |           | |
| |     | | |       IOS       | |    | |       | |        | |        | | |           | |
| | OSX | | | +-------------+ | | TV | | WATCH | | BRIDGE | | VISION | | | DRIVERKIT | |
| |     | | | | MACCATALYST | | |    | |       | |        | |        | | |           | |
| |     | | | +-------------+ | |    | |       | |        | |        | | |           | |
| |     | | +-----------------+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ +--------+ | |           | |
| +-----+ +------------------------------------------------------------+ +-----------+ |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The reason why MAC covers everything is because all the other operating systems are in fact stripped down macOS systems, so MAC has become a synonym for "Apple Platform". The other platforms on this level are:

- `TARGET_OS_WIN32`
- `TARGET_OS_WINDOWS`
- `TARGET_OS_UNIX`
- `TARGET_OS_LINUX`
- `TARGET_OS_MAC`

And iPhone OS (today named iOS) was the first stripped down version of macOS, all other systems are modified version of iPhone OS, that's why the layer below `TARGET_OS_MAC` is split into:

- `TARGET_OS_OSX`
- `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`
- `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR`
- `TARGET_OS_DRIVERKIT`

And `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` has the following sublayers:

- `TARGET_OS_IOS`
- `TARGET_OS_TV`
- `TARGET_OS_WATCH`
- `TARGET_OS_VISION`
- `TARGET_OS_BRIDGE`

There is one final sublayer below `TARGET_OS_IOS` and that is `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST`. "Mac Catalyst" is not truly a platform of its own but instead it is a subset of the iOS API extended with desktop API functionality. This added desktop functionality is how iPadOS differs from iOS on iPhones: They are both iOS but iPadOS has additional functionality that standard iOS on iPhone has not. The entire Catalyst API was backported to macOS, so apps that are limited to the Catalyst API can run on iPads and on Macs without further modification. Note that most normal iPhone apps can also run on Macs but only on ARM Macs, whereas Catalyst apps can also run on Intel Macs, as the Catalyst APIs are also available for x86_64 systems.

Missing in this picture is `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` which is always set when code runs in a simulator; no matter what simulator. E.g. if you want a piece of code to only be used when you run in an iOS simulator but not in other simulators (tvOS, watchOS), then you would use

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IOS

#endif
```

Note that this code will not run on a real iOS device either.

Also noteworthy are the defines for different target CPUs:

- `TARGET_CPU_PPC`
- `TARGET_CPU_PPC64`
- `TARGET_CPU_68K`
- `TARGET_CPU_X86`
- `TARGET_CPU_X86_64`
- `TARGET_CPU_ARM`
- `TARGET_CPU_ARM64`
- `TARGET_CPU_MIPS`
- `TARGET_CPU_SPARC`
- `TARGET_CPU_ALPHA`

and the defines for the following properties:

- `TARGET_RT_LITTLE_ENDIAN`: Generated code uses little endian format for integers
- `TARGET_RT_BIG_ENDIAN`: Generated code uses big endian format for integers
- `TARGET_RT_64_BIT`: Generated code uses 64-bit pointers
- `TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO`: `TARGET_OS_MAC` is true and Mach-O/dlyd runtime is used

All other target conditionals are deprecated or pretty much useless in practice.